# databricks delta format file not able to read

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I am using <spark.version>3.1.1</spark.version> with "delta" lake io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0. in my project.

While reading "delta" file I am getting below error

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> ShuffleMapStage 4 ($anonfun$call$1 at DatabricksLogging.scala:77) has
> failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure
> reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9   at
> org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.BlockTransferMessage$Decoder.fromByteBuffer(BlockTransferMessage.java:71)

Any help , how to fix this issue?

Actual Error while reading :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 4 ($anonfun$call$1 at DatabricksLogging.scala:77) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.BlockTransferMessage$Decoder.fromByteBuffer(BlockTransferMessage.java:71)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.receive(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:180)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:748)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:663)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.sort_addToSorter_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.actions.InMemoryLogReplay.append(InMemoryLogReplay.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Snapshot.$anonfun$stateReconstruction$3(Snapshot.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec.$anonfun$doExecute$3(objects.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$getOrCompute$1(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1388)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1298)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1362)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1186)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.BlockTransferMessage$Decoder.fromByteBuffer(BlockTransferMessage.java:71)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.receive(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:180)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:207)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:142)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    ... 1 more 
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2410)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2380)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:467)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.forTable(DeltaLog.scala:404)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog(DeltaTableV2.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.toBaseRelation(DeltaTableV2.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:284)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:232)
```

**After corrrecting delta to version 1.0.0 above error resolved but getting below new error while reading.**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.V2TableWithV1Fallback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

I am currently using

```
export SPARK_HOME=/spark-folder/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7-hive1.2
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
...
--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0
```

Comment: Must be something with the joins you are doing with the read data.. Why dont you just read and say show, to check if your syntax is correct.
If you are not using any joins, please edit the post by adding the code snippet..

Comment: @Betta thanks for quick reply , i am not using any joins... but i have one   union i.e. Dataset<Row> unionedDs = biDs.unionByName(intermediateDF);       I have to get read two  sets of data for two different datasets.

Answer (score 2):

With Spark 3.1.1 you must use Delta 1.0.x - currently 1.0.0. 0.8.0 is compatible only with Spark 3.0.x (see [compatibility matrix](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html#compatibility-with-apache-spark)):

[image]

But most probably that you have an external shuffle service that is running on incompatible version of the Spark, like, your code is on 3.1.1, and shuffle service is on 3.0.x

Comment: let me check it ... please tell me , there is another spark job which is using 3.0.x with 0.8.x writes a "delta" file ... i am reading it with 3.1.x with 1.0.x , will that works ?

Comment: yes, it should work without problem. Your stacktrace shows the problem at Spark itself, not inside the Delta

Comment: thank it resolved that error now getting another error.

Comment: update the question ... please check i am using ...export SPARK_HOME=/spark-folder/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7-hive1.2
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
...
--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0

Comment: with Spark 3.0.2 you need to use Delta 0.8.0. Unfortunately delta packages are binary incompatible between Spark 3.0 & 3.1

Comment: I tried that one too , but no luck so i upgraded spark and delta version but still getting same error ... can you please have a look and advice please ,... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68730904/illegalargumentexception-unknown-message-type-9-while-reading-delta-file

Comment: The later error is showing that it you are running 1.0.0 on Spark 3.0

Comment: i am using 3.1.2 spark version in my pom.xml and spark-submit i am using export SPARK_HOME=spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2 this.... where it showing i am using spark 3.0 ?

Comment: The message `org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9` looks like version mismatch between shuffle service & Spark job. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27780 - can you try to add `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true` to your spark-submit?

Comment: I lowered the spark and delta versions.... now i am getting new error , any clue what is wrong here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749527/nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-hadoop-conf-configuration-reloadexistingconfigurat

Comment: both --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true and --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true are added the script spark-submit

Comment: if i remove shuffle service it throws error Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Dynamic allocation of executors requires the external shuffle service. You may enable this through spark.shuffle.service.enabled.

Comment: have you added `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true` when you removed   shuffle service config? you need to have only this one