# IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9 while reading "delta" file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I am using <spark.version>3.1.2</spark.version> with "delta" lake io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0 in my project.

**While reading "delta" file I am getting below IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9  error**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 4 ($anonfun$apply$2 at DatabricksLogging.scala:77) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9  at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.BlockTransferMessage$Decoder.fromByteBuffer(BlockTransferMessage.java:71)  at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.receive(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:80)    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)     at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    ... 1 more 
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.forTable(DeltaLog.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:305)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:265)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 4 ($anonfun$apply$2 at DatabricksLogging.scala:77) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.BlockTransferMessage$Decoder.fromByteBuffer(BlockTransferMessage.java:71)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9     at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.BlockTransferMessage$Decoder.fromByteBuffer(BlockTransferMessage.java:71)  at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    ... 1 more 
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
```

**I am submitting spark job as below**

```
export SPARK_HOME=/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.9.2,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0,org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark-bundle_2.12:0.6.0
```

what is wrong here ? any clue ? any help highly appriciated.

Comment: do you have `spark.shuffle.service.enabled` in your spark? https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/external-shuffle-service/ExternalShuffleService/, https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/external-shuffle-service-apache-spark/read

Comment: Check this -> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27780

Comment: @Alex Ott ..yes its enabled..--conf spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints=true \
--conf spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking=true \
--conf spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking.shuffle=true \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=600 \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=850 \
--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1 \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \

Comment: if it's enabled, then it means that shuffle service is running on different version of Spark than your job... I posted the same Jira as Mohana in your previous question

Comment: @Alex Ott so what should be the way out for me ?

Comment: either use the same version of Spark that is used for shuffle service.  If it's not possible, either disable use of it, or if you're using dynamic allocation, try to use `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true` instead as described in the documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation

Comment: @Alex Ott, thank you , let me try it , where should i know which version of shffle service been used. hope it would show in sparkUI.

Comment: I'm not sure about that - usually it's a separate process in Yarn, or something like

Comment: @AlexOtt I used --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true but still no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered something similar and similar to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33093

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9
at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.BlockTransferMessage$Decoder.fromByteBuffer(BlockTransferMessage.java:71)
at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.receive(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:81)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:157)
```

the following helped me as well

```
spark.shuffle.useOldFetchProtocol=true
```

Comment: thanks for this , may I know what is the actual root cause for issue , and how this would fix ? If I write a new delta file data , will it be write using new protocol or use old one ?

Comment: I see this " park.shuffle.useOldFetchProtocol¶
Whether to use the old protocol while doing the shuffle block fetching. It is only enabled while we need the compatibility in the scenario of new Spark version job fetching shuffle blocks from old version external shuffle service". .. How to enable or use  new version external shuffle service " ???

Comment: can you comment on above question