# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations()V

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, hadoop2, delta-lake

I am using <spark.version>3.0.2</spark.version> with detla version 0.8.0 in my project.
and running with

```
export SPARK_HOME=/pkg/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7-hive1.2
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \

--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.9.2,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.9.2,org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark-bundle_2.12:0.6.0
```

**I am getting below error**

```
 User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations()V
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.addDeprecatedKeys(S3AFileSystem.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.<clinit>(S3AFileSystem.java:187)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:171)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:232)
```

**What is wrong here ?? any clue how to fix it ?**

**Tried with**

```
export SPARK_HOME=/pkg/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.9.1-custom
```

**Getting error**

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 4 ($anonfun$call$1 at DatabricksLogging.scala:77) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: 9     at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.BlockTransferMessage$Decoder.fromByteBuffer(BlockTransferMessage.java:71)  at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)    ... 1 more 
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLog.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$$anon$3.call(DeltaLog.scala:470)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Spark is compiled with Hadoop 2.7, but you're trying to execute your code with Hadoop 2.9. Remove Hadoop 2.9 coordinates from `--packages` command

Comment: Alex but i dont find spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.9-hive1.2 download in the spark downloads.

Comment: why do you need Hadoop 2.9 at all?

Comment: tried with export SPARK_HOME=/pkg/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.9.1-custom getting same error.

Comment: Real question - what functionality do you need from Hadoop 2.9 if you're using it?

Comment: Hi Alex sir , when i download from spark site i.e. https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html itself spark is coming with hadoop jars.. so i used it.

Comment: Can you please help me what went wrong here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080797/unable-to-write-parquet-file-due-error-sparkexception-job-aborted-fileforma